# Comparing 2 lists of dictionaries

Tags: python

I want to return True of two lists of dictionaries are memberwise equal (member being the content of each dictionary, **disregarding order of lists**), else return False. What is good way to do that in python?

Eg, if a = [dict1, dict2] and b = [dict2, dict1], then a is equal to b. (dict1's  and dict2's keys and values must match.)

Here's my way:

```
def _compare(self, a,b):
        if len(a) != len(b):
            return False

        for d in a:
            if d in b:
                continue
            else:
                return False
        return True
```

Comment: "two lists of dictionaries are memberwise equal (disregarding order)" Do you mean disregarding order in the lists, or in the dictionaries?

Comment: `a == b` *will* disregard order so I think normal dict comparison does exactly what you want already??

Comment: You need to be clearer, are you comparing the keys or the values or both? provide some sample inputs and outputs

Comment: Updated problem statement.

Comment: Could you clarify whether there can be duplicate dictionaries within _the same_ list, i.e. could `a` and `b` be `[dict1, dict1, dict2]` and `[dict1, dict2, dict2]` respectively, and whether that case should yield `True` or `False`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(The question is a bit ambiguous. As I understand it, `a` and `b` are both lists containing dictionaries, and you want to check whether the two lists contain the same dictionaries, in any order.)

You could just use the `all` builtin, although this will be rather slow for long lists, having O(n²):

```
>>> lst1 = [{1:2, 3:4}, {5:6, 7:8}]
>>> lst2 = [{7:8, 5:6}, {3:4, 1:2}]
>>> len(lst1) == len(lst2) and all(x in lst2 for x in lst1)
True
```

Better convert the `list` of `dict` to `set` of `frozenset` holding the dicts items,having O(n):

```
>>> set_of_tuples = lambda l: set(frozenset(d.items()) for d in l)
>>> set_of_tuples(lst1)
set([frozenset([(1, 2), (3, 4)]), frozenset([(5, 6), (7, 8)])])
>>> set_of_tuples(lst1) == set_of_tuples(lst2)
True
```

Addendum: This requires that the values in the dicts are hashable. Also, it assumes no duplicate dicts within the same list (but in this case you code would not work, either, so I think this assumption is valid). If there are duplicates, use `Counter` as shown in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52042832/1639625).

Comment: `all(x in lst2 for x in lst1)` only ensures that every dict in `lst1` is in `lst2`, but not that every dict in `lst2` is in `lst1`, so your solution would return `True` when `lst2` has dicts that `lst1` does not. It also does not check for equal numbers of duplicates, so if `a = [dict1, dict2, dict1]` and `b = [dict2, dict1, dict2]`, your solution would incorrectly return `True`.

Comment: @blhsing You are right about `all`, I fixed that. About duplicates: Right about that, too, but I already addressed that.

Comment: If `lst1 = [dict1, dict2, dict1]` and `lst2 = [dict2, dict1, dict3]`, then `len(lst1) == len(lst2) and all(x in lst2 for x in lst1)` would still incorrectly return `True`.

Comment: Moreover, if `lst1 = [dict1, dict2, dict1]` and `lst2 = [dict2, dict1, dict2]`, then `len(lst1) == len(lst2) and all(x in lst2 for x in lst1)` would also incorrectly return `True`.

Comment: @blhsing As I said, I already addressed that my code does not handle duplicates and linked to your answer for that case. But as I understand the question there are no duplicates (derived from OP's current code, assuming it is working, since OP does not state what's wrong with it).

Comment: Ah I see. My bad. Saw your update to your original solution of `all(x in lst2 for x in lst1)` and thought that was all that was updated.

Comment: I agree that handling duplicates may very well not be part of OP's requirements, in which case your solution would work indeed.

Answer (score 1):

This is for comparing members nicely:

```
a.keys() == b.keys()
```

`keys()` returns a view over the members of a dictionary.

To make this work with 2 lists of dicts, just wrap it in a comprehension:

```
[a.keys() == b.keys() for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]
```

It will return a list of True's and False's.

If you want to know it they are all equal, then just wrap it with `all()`, so the final result is:

```
all([a.keys() == b.keys() for a, b in zip(list1, list2)])
```

#### Benchmarks

```
a = {}
b = {}
for i in range(100_0000):
    a[i] = i
    b[i] = i

In [10]: %timeit a==b # wrong, but just for comparison
11.6 ms ± 265 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [11]: %timeit a.keys()==b.keys()
16.9 ms ± 209 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [17]: %timeit _compare(a, b)
30.6 ms ± 633 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [18]: %timeit set(a.keys()) == set(b.keys())
71 ms ± 1.04 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Aren't `a` and `b` lists in the OP's example?

Comment: I think `a` and `b` are lists of dicts here; also, just comparing the keys does not warrant equality of the values.

Comment: Yea guys, sorry... I guess I only half-read it, based only on the code snippet.

Comment: Now in your updated version, if _does_ regard order, which OP did not want (and neither does OP's current code), and it still ignores the values.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: @tobias_k I just tested that `.keys()` disregards order? Simple to test on 3.7. Note that `.keys()` does not return a list but a view over the keys.

Comment: @PascalVKooten Sure, `keys` does, but `zip` certainly does not.

Comment: @tobias_k that does not change anything in my examples? Using zip will just make the variables point to the dict objects, for which keys will return a view.

Comment: I guess we have a different understanding of the question. I added mine to my answer, and maybe you should do the same, so that OP and others know the prerequisites for our solutions.

Comment: @tobias_k OP's code shows no sign of caring about values :)

Comment: @PascalVKooten Only if you assume `a` and `b` to be `dict`, which, again, I do not. Instead, I am pretty sure that `d` is the `dict` here, and `a` and `b` are the lists.

Comment: @tobias_k that turned out to be way more ambiguous than I thought ^^ Looks like your answer might be right.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the dicts in the lists to tuples of items first and then use `collections.Counter` to compare the two lists regardless of order:

```
from collections import Counter
def compare(a, b):
    return Counter(tuple(d.items()) for d in a) == Counter(tuple(d.items()) for d in b)
```

so that the comparison of the following two lists of dicts that are memberwise-equal:

```
compare(
    [{1: 2, 2: 3}, {3: 4, 5: 6}, {3: 4, 5: 6}],
    [{3: 4, 5: 6}, {1: 2, 2: 3}, {3: 4, 5: 6}]
)
```

returns `True`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to compare the set of values:

```
da = { 1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
db = { 3:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c'}

set(db.values()) == set(da.values())
```